# C linux shared memory cannot store large integer value

Tags: c, linux

I'm still quite a noob at programming and I ran into an issue which I could not solve by myself so I'm trying to seeking some help online but could not find any solutions.

I'm currently trying to create a program in linux which utilises shared memory to transfer integers between two programs. I could successfully transfer small integers such as 50 or 99, however I could not write values larger than around 100 without them changing into a completely different random value whenever I try to read it from the segment.

I've been sitting and looking at my code for hours and couldn't figure it out.
Could any of you more skilled programmers give me some advice as to what may be the cause of this issue?

Thanks

This is the first program which writes the integer testValue to the segment, however if test value is a bit higher than 100 say 150, the output would turn into another value. Values such less than 100 usually work.

```
ps = shmPointer;
for(Count = 1; Count <= atoi(argv[1]); Count++)
    {
        *ps++ = testValue;
    }

*ps = (char)NULL;

while(*shmPointer != (char)'*')
{
    sleep(1);
}
```

For the segment size i did a 
`#define SHMSZ 100`
and my shmget call was `shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, IPC_CREAT | 0666);`

Below is the code for the other program which retrieves the integer stored within the segment:

```
ps = shmPointer;

for(ps = shmPointer; *ps != (char)NULL; ps++)
{
    printf("Value: %d\n", (int)*ps)
}

printf("\n");

*shm = '*';
```

Comment: Not without seeing the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: We need more information to help you. Without showing us your code, how do you expect us to help you, honestly? Please thoroughly read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) - in particular, ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added the part of the code where I write an integer into the segment along with the line where I called shmget()

Comment: Assuming ps is of type "char *", what you are trying won't work. You cannot store an arbitrary integer in a char (only -128 to +127 can be stored in a signed char).

Comment: Also, when you use the format specifier "%d" printf expects an int; you are lying to the compiler when you cast a dereferenceed pointer-to-char to an int, which it is not.

Comment: Yes it was the char * causing the issue and thanks for the information / advices regarding both the programming problem and how this site works. I would give you guys a +1 if I could, but I don't know how to lol..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ps is of type "char *", what you are trying won't work. You cannot store an arbitrary integer in a char (only -128 to +127 can be stored in a signed char). – FredK